# Django custom save method: takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an issue with a custom save method for a model in Django.
The error returned is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bpipat/.virtualenvs/usertest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/bpipat/.virtualenvs/usertest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 78, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bpipat/.virtualenvs/usertest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bpipat/.virtualenvs/usertest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 399, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/bpipat/.virtualenvs/usertest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 396, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bpipat/.virtualenvs/usertest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 52, in create
    self.object = serializer.save(force_insert=True)
  File "/Users/bpipat/.virtualenvs/usertest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 560, in save
    self.save_object(self.object, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bpipat/.virtualenvs/usertest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 935, in save_object
    obj.save(**kwargs)
TypeError: save() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

The models used here are as follows. The idea is a kind of ERP for wine bottle which populates users cellars (vinibars).
A bottle has 4 foreign keys: 1 user, 1 wine and two movements which define where the bottle is and whether it has been rated (=drunk)

```
class Wine(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Container(models.Model):

    CONTAINER_TYPE = (
    ('cellar', 'Cellar'),
    ('vinibar', 'Vinibar'),
    ('history', 'History'),
    )

    container_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CONTAINER_TYPE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_id')


class Movement(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    start = models.ForeignKey(Container, related_name='movement_start')
    finish = models.ForeignKey(Container, related_name='movement_finish')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Bottle(models.Model):
    wine = models.ForeignKey(Wine, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    mounted = models.ForeignKey(Movement, related_name='bottle_mounted')
    rated = models.ForeignKey(Movement, null=True, blank=True, default=None, related_name='bottle_rated')
    date_mounted = models.DateTimeField() 
    date_rated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(5)], null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

The custom save method for Bottle is below. The error occurs when I try to create a new bottle in my Django Rest API

The specificity of this save function is to create the Movement object for which Bottle has a ForeignKey with the user and wine arguments of the save function

```
def save(self, wine, user, force_insert=True, *args, **kwargs):
    d = datetime.now()
    self.wine = wine #wine referencing issue
    self.user = user
    v = Container.objects.get(container_type='vinibar', user=user)
    c = Container.objects.get(container_type='cellar', user=admin) 
    m = Movement(date=d, start=c, finish=v) #quantity=quantity?
    self.mounted = m
    self.date_mounted = d
    super(Bottle, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I don't understand to which argument the error refers to, I've tried pretty much all I could think of..

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: where is the actual code that calls `save`

Comment: @SimeonVisser I've added the stacktrace. 
The save method is directly in the Django Rest Framework API  which create generic ViewSets to create and edit models

Answer (score 0):

Your `save()` method requires at least three arguments: `self`, `wine` and `user`:

```
def save(self, wine, user, force_insert=True, *args, **kwargs):
```

That means Django REST framework can't call `save()` as follows when `kwargs` contains only one value:

```
obj.save(**kwargs)
```

You need to change the signature of `save()` to:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

You can then obtain the values of `wine`, `user` and other arguments from `args` and `kwargs` (if they happen to be passed by Django REST framework at all).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. My problem is that the mounted Movement object needs to be created just before the object is saved.
At which point should I give the super.save() function the arguments which are computed above?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your mounted variable is not defined when it is assigned to self.mounted

```
self.mounted = mounted
```

Does fixing that help?

Comment: Thanks for that, it was in the initial code but I had removed it for testing. It does indeed need to be there, but it doesn't fix the problem